# Quick Comment Option to Contributors

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, comments

Recently I felt that one feature is really required on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

I am active user since I love **Stack Overflow**. I love to review questions and visit this **[Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&pageSize=15)** tab for each new questions.

I felt many times that new users just posting their question without any code or whatever he/she has done. So contributor has to put some common comments every time. Some example I wrote as follow which I would like to have as quick comment.

Every time contributor has to comment like:

- Please, post your code.
- What you have done so far?
- Have you tried anything?
- Please add the code where you are using `xxx xxx xxx code or variables`
- Welcome to Stack Overflow, Have you visit once [Code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

  etc, etc...

There are many suggestions that we can take as an example but we can give feature to contributors **who can comment easily using template.**

Comment: Do not think so. I think this is different.

Comment: This already exists: when reviewing posts flagged as not an answer or very low quality, or if the post fails to meet a given automatic quality heuristic, users have the option of placing canned comments.

Comment: Additionally, as this question is only about Stack Overflow, we have to mark it as "off-topic" here; please ask on Meta Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: No problem, You can mark as off-topic. I will post there but your first comment is not relevant actually. I am talking about templates to comment, not for close vote.

Comment: There is an addon for this: https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se